# I want to get id of product selected on opportunity record

Tags: opportunity, lookup

I want to get id of product selected on opportunity record. There is lookup relationship between Opportunity and product. All I want is id of the product selected by user on that record. below is my code.

```
    public without sharing class Test {

    public static void Org (List<Opportunity> organisations){
   Set<Id> OrgIds = new Set<Id>();


 for(Opportunity o : organisations){

            OrgIds.add(o.Id);
        }

 for( Product__c product : [SELECT ID, Name, Product_ID__c FROM Product__c WHERE ID IN :OrgIds])
        {
        system.debug('I am in here' + product.ID );
       }

}
}
```

Product__C is a Custom object

Added lookup between opportunity and product object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lookup field is on the Opportunity then you would need to query the opportunity object not the Product__c object. I'm guessing something like this:

```
public without sharing class Test {

  public static void Org (List<Opportunity> organisations){
    Set<Id> prodIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity o : organisations) {
      prodIds.add(o.product__c);
    }

    for( Product__c product : [SELECT ID, Name, Product_ID__c FROM Product__c WHERE ID IN :prodIds])
    {
      system.debug('I am in here' + product.Product_ID__c );
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: but if I query on opportunity how would I get Id of product? As product is lookup on opportunity I have tried doing Product__r.Product_ID__c but that also gives error. 
Loop variable must be Sobject or list of opportuity.

Comment: @Ricky Product_ID__c is the ID of the product. The relationship field holds the ID of the related object.

Comment: So do you mean I can simply query product__c lookup field on opportunity ? that will give me id of that as well?

Comment: @Ricky yup, that is correct!

Comment: ok I am still confused here. Let me write query here again
[SELECT ID,Name, Product__c from Opportunity where Product__c IN : OrgIds] is this correct?

Comment: @Ricky If Product__c is the API name of the lookup field then yes, hard for me to say without knowing your org, but if you look at the field on opportunity and verify that is the api name of that field then yes that is correct.

Comment: Ya Product__C is an api name of lookup field on Opportunity. I have tried running the same  query but I am still getting the same error. "Loop variable must be an SObject or list of Opportunity"

Comment: @Ricky I missed changed the object type, fixed my answer and also you need the variable name for the for loop in the sys debug.

Comment: New quer is [SELECT ID,Name, Product__c from Opportunity where Product__c IN : OrgIds] as there is no Product_ID__C field on opportunity. I had to replace that with Product__c as we discussed. I have made that changes but log does not reflect the debug statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29989/discussion-between-ricky-and-jenny-b).

Answer (score 0):

The Ids that you're gathering in the for loop before the query are for Opportunities, not Product__c.

Your query should be on Opportunity, not on Product__c.

Comment: but how would I be able to get product_ID__C from product if I query opportunity?